# JSF CDI target unreachable

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, jsf-2.2

I am trying to run a JSF demo in JBoss Wildfly. It's from the quickstart demo with the Wildfly. Here there are two file, CreateController.java and the JSF file. I received this error:

```
Context Path:/wildfly-greeter
Servlet Path:/faces
Path Info:/create.xhtml
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: /create.xhtml @29,75 value="#{newdUser.username}":     Target Unreachable, identifier 'newdUser' resolved to null
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
```

Why is the producer field "newUser" is unreachable? I didn't change anything in the demo.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CreateController {

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Inject
private UserDao userDao;

@Named
@Produces
@RequestScoped
private User newUser = new User();

public void create() {
    try {
        userDao.createUser(newUser);
        String message = "A new user with id " + newUser.getId() + " has been created successfully";
        facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = "An error has occured while creating the user (see log for details)";
        facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
    }
}
}
```

CreateControl.xhtml

```
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="username">Enter username:</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{newdUser.username}" />
            <h:message for="username" />
    </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton action="#{createController.create}"
            value="Add User" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you accidentally put a 'd' in

```
value="#{newdUser.username}"
```

instead of

```
value="#{newUser.username}"
```

It's not in the source at [Github](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/greeter/src/main/webapp/create.xhtml) either.

IMO you can simplify the code a bit like

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CreateController {

  @Inject
  private UserDao userDao;

  private User newUser = new User(); // +getter/setter

  public void create() {
    try {
      userDao.createUser(newUser);
      String message = "A new user with id " + newUser.getId() + " has been created successfully";
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String message = "An error has occured while creating the user (see log for details)";
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="username">Enter username:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{createController.newUser.username}" />
        <h:message for="username" />
</h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton action="#{createController.create}" value="Add User" />
```

Hope it works.